# Отображение компонента MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно изменить вид MenuStrip в Visual Studio? Единственное что хоть как то меняет вид это свойство RenderMode, но это не то. Нужно что-то вроде как на скриншоте ниже в Sublime Text. Там нет этих рамок вокруг меню, цвет выделения приятный и ширина пунктов сверху такая же как ширина слова. Все аккуратно выглядит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уменьшить ширину - ставьте `Padding` в `0` (как у самого меню, так у пунктов).